# Reproduce jquery match() in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, match

I have written the code in javascript but i need it to happen in serverside, The function gets the part of the requested url and if it's match my switch it's change the ducoment title.

Here is the Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
 e=window.location.href;
 if(e.match(/\\?case=(.*)/)){
  x=e.match(/\\?case=(.*)/);
  y=x[1];
  switch(y){
  case :"t"
    document.title ="Title2";
  break;
  case :"s"
    document.title ="Title3";
  break;
  default:
    /* code ... */
  break;
}
}
 });
```

In this code if my url is "http://url.com/?case=t" the title of document going to change to "Title2".

How can i write it in php? the problem is getting the url match!

Comment: Why not just use `$_GET['case']` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean getting the variable case? Because that's what you used in JavaScript

And if so, an example in PHP would be having this in the header

```
<?php
$case = $_GET['case'];
switch ($case) {
  case 't':
    $title = 'Title 2';
    break;
}
echo "<title>". $title . "</title";
?>
```

Comment: I was looking for something like $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] but in my case I can use your method. Didn't even think about your solution! Tnx a lot!